# Is there a keyboard shortcut to navigate between tags in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a quick way to jump to the corresponding open/close tag when editing HTML in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, not currently.

Visual Studio Code does have a keyboard shortcut for jumping to matching braces/brackets/parentheses (`Ctrl + Shift + \` on Windows, `Cmd + Shift + \` on Mac), however it does not have support for jumping to closing tags in HTML.

If you feel like it, you could always [submit a feature request to the Visual Studio Code team](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code), and maybe you'll see the feature added in a future release.

Comment: It's been five years. Any sign of this functionality?